Istio Ingress Gateway not become ready
I am installing istio to my cluster and have a weird behavior.
EKS version I am using is 1.28 and I have tested with istio version of 1.18.3, 1.19.10 and 1.22.1.
The yaml configurations file for the installation:
# istio-1-19-10.yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: minimal
  revision: <revision, e.g 1-19-10 for version of 1.19.10>
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway-<revision>
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          replicaCount: 1
          serviceAnnotations:
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:XXX:XXX:certificate/XXX"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "600"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"

Install cmd:
istioctl-1-18-3 install -f istio-1-18-3.yaml
istioctl-1-19-10 install -f istio-1-19-10.yaml
istioctl-1-22-1 install -f istio-1-22-1.yaml


The ingress gateway could not become ready for version of 1.19.10 and 1.22.1, but version 1.18.3 work!.
Logs:

1-19-10

  2024-06-27T06:59:38.510374Z   warning envoy config external/envoy/source/extensions/config_subscription/grpc/grpc_subscription_impl.cc:128    gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.listener.v3.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_8443: Didn't find a registered implementation for 'envoy.listener.proxy_protocol' with type URL: '' 0.0.0.0_8080: Didn't find a registered implementation for 'envoy.listener.proxy_protocol' with type URL: ''   thread=15 2024-06-27T06:59:39.169095Z   warn    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config received from XDS server, but was rejected: cds updates: 2 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 1 rejected


1-22-1

2024-06-27T07:10:13.616063Z warning envoy config external/envoy/source/extensions/config_subscription/grpc/delta_subscription_state.cc:269  delta config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.listener.v3.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_8080: Didn't find a registered implementation for 'envoy.listener.proxy_protocol' with type URL: ''
0.0.0.0_8443: Didn't find a registered implementation for 'envoy.listener.proxy_protocol' with type URL: ''
    thread=15
2024-06-27T07:10:13.616095Z warning envoy config external/envoy/source/extensions/config_subscription/grpc/grpc_subscription_impl.cc:138    gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.listener.v3.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_8080: Didn't find a registered implementation for 'envoy.listener.proxy_protocol' with type URL: ''
0.0.0.0_8443: Didn't find a registered implementation for 'envoy.listener.proxy_protocol' with type URL: ''
    thread=15
2024-06-27T07:10:14.187106Z warn    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config received from XDS server, but was rejected: cds updates: 1 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 1 rejected

From 1.22.0, Istio use Delta xDS as default, so in theory, version 1.18.3 and 1.19.10 should have a same behavior. I mean they should both fail or success.
Did you face with these issue before? I haven't found any solution or documentation mention about this. Thanks.
